# What is Clipboard data in android

Tags: android

i would like to  know follow things.

what is clipboard data then where we have used clipboard data in android device.

Thanks and advance

Comment: Do you know what is ClipBoard in Windows OS  ?

Comment: [ClipBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_(computing)) is an area where you store your `copied` data for future `paste` activity.

Comment: It's a memory area where the copied contents are stored. So you can retrieve them for pasting.

Comment: i have nexus tablet ,i copied some content from google  .so how to s store  content in clipboard memory

Comment: @user3539885 check the developer links in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClipBoardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) in Android is allow to copy & paste functionality. Developer can store the `copied` content in to ClipBoard and retrieve the stored content for further `paste` functionality.

Developer can store & retrieve String,integer,binary etc kind of data.

Check this [Copy and Paste on Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html).